# resize img src inside fixed div

Tags: image, html, resize, tumblr, src

How do I resize the visible portion of my image inside `postbox-inner`?  How do I resize the overall box of `postbox-outer`?

I'm basically looking for smaller images because a lot of them are invariably low-res and tend to pixelate in ugly ways, or alternately a way to resize my grid.

Preferably both.

```
<!--{block:Photo}-->
<div class="postbox-outer">
    <div class="postbox-inner" 
        <a href="{Permalink}">
            <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" border="0" />
            {block:Caption}<span class="desc">{Caption}</span>{/block:Caption}
        </a>
    </div>
</div>      
<!--{/block:Photo}-->
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want the images to be displayed at it's best possible size. If it's a huge image you want it constrained within the div. If it's a small image you don't want it to fill the div. The best thing I could suggest is to set the max-width for the image to 100%. Here's the CSS rule:

**img { max-width: 100%; }**

Hopefully this should work out fine. Do let me know if this answers your question.